# PHP PDO - Why is the result of a FETCH_ASSO() on a LAST_INSERT_ID() not indexed with the column name?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

All,

I have some PHP PDO code that looks like this:

```
<?php
 ...
 $query=$dbh->prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
 $query->execute();
 $result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // returns an array indexed by column name as returned in result set - here column name is "userID" in the DB
 print_r($result);
 ...
```

When I run this, the result of `print_r($result);` is something like `Array([LAST_INSERT_ID()]=>18)`.  Why is the array indexed on `[LAST_INSERT_ID()]` as opposed to `userID`, which is the name of my column in the data table?  The PHP manual says:

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set

What am I missing?

Thanks,

JDelage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are not selecting the column, but the result of that MySQL function.

You could use...

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS `userID`
```

Comment: Alex - I'm confused.  What does `column name` refer to in the PHP manual definition (`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set`)?

Comment: @JDelage In this example, the column name is the name of the MySQL function (`LAST_INSERT_ID()`). If you did `SELECT \`userID\``, `userID` would be the column name.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [PDO::LastInsertId()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) instead

Comment: What is the advantage of doing that over using the MySQL query?  Is it the layer of abstraction that would allow me to change db engine?

Comment: @JDelage: well, actually I don't know. For me it is just a handy shortcut, that requires less keystrokes.